# Changed from praw to asyncpraw, now geting "AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'comments'"

Tags: python, async-await, praw

I have a small script running that is supposed to pull all comments from all users contained in a list as written here:

```
import asyncpraw
import pandas as pd

reddit = asyncpraw.Reddit(
    user_agent = "XXX",
    client_id = "XXX",
    client_secret = "XXX",
    username = "XXX",
    password = "XXX"
)


dataset_one_author #(just a list of usernames)

body = []
author = []
created_utc = []
score = []
subreddit_id = []
permalink = []

count = 0


for index, row in dataset_one_author.iterrows():
    author_row = row['author']
   
    #try:
        
    count = count + 1
    print(count)

    for comment in reddit.redditor(author_row).comments.new(limit=None):
    
        body.append(comment.body)
        author.append(author_row)
        created_utc.append(comment.created_utc)
        score.append(comment.score)
        subreddit_id.append(comment.subreddit_id)
        permalink.append(comment.permalink)
     
        
            
    # except:
        
    #     body.append("user_deleted")
    #     author.append("user_deleted")
    #     created_utc.append("user_deleted")
    #     score.append("user_deleted")
    #     subreddit_id.append("user_deleted")
    #     permalink.append("user_deleted")
    #     #continue
        

a = pd.DataFrame(author, columns =['author'])
a['body'] = pd.DataFrame(body)
a['created_utc'] = pd.DataFrame(created_utc)
a['score'] = pd.DataFrame(score)
a['subreddit_id'] = pd.DataFrame(subreddit_id)
a['permalink'] = pd.DataFrame(permalink)
```

When I run this script with normal praw, it runs fine (albeit pretty slow). As advised I changed to asyncpraw and am now getting the "AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'comments'. I know that I need to "await" the task but cannot figure out where, any help would be greatly appreciated. If you by any chance also spot a glaring performance issue, I would also be very glad to hear about it.

(I have commented out the try/except to get the asyncpraw error - try/except here is normally meant to catch 404 errors from deleted users).

Comment: The glaring "error" I can see is that you may be mixing up `pd.Series` and `pd.DataFrame`. Also, you'd get by easier by just creating a list-of-dicts first (instead of six separate lists), then passing it directly to `pd.DataFrame`.

Comment: (Also, just using `asyncpraw` won't magically make your code faster.)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you haven't awaited the async iterator, so instead of

```
for comment in reddit.redditor(author_row).comments.new(limit=None):
```

try doing

```
async for comment in reddit.redditor(author_row).comments.new(limit=None):
```

Comment: now it's giving me "SyntaxError: 'async for' outside async function"

Comment: You will need to read up on how async Python works, then.